# Node.js installation error

Tags: linux, node.js, installation

I have installed Node.js, NVM and NPM according to : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

My working directory looks like this:

**Working_Files\WebRTC**  which contains the files:

- package.json
- server.js

and

**Working_Files\WebRTC\views** which contains an index file:

```
index.ejs
```

In Working_Files\WebRTC, in order to run the server, using:

```
  node server.js
```

every time I have to repeat the process explained in the installation, otherwise I receive the error:

```
 node server.js 
 The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
  * node
  * nodejs-legacy
  Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

where the error does stand please?

Thank you

Comment: What part of the manual did you reach? Or did you successfully complete all of it?

Comment: sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install node.js
     sudo apt-get install npm
     sudo apt-get install build-essential
--------------------------------------------------
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
    nvm install ....
    nvm use ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `sudo ln -s "$(which nodejs)" /usr/bin/node`

And run again `node server.js`

Comment: Thanks, worked very well, in your view where the problem resided?

Comment: In apt-get package manager, there is another program using the 'node' command, so ... NodeJS package uses nodejs command. Using sudo ln -s "$ (which nodejs)" / usr / bin / node ', you change nodejs from node :)